# Hi , is there a way in the blender api to get the fullpath of an object which is multiple groups ?..here is an example of maya

Tags: python

[image: **an example for the result i need**]

Hi , is there a way in the blender api  to get the fullpath of an object  which is multiple groups ?..here is an example of maya